# How would I create this T-SQL subquery?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, inner-query

I am losing my touch here. In the old days I would come up with a super T-SQL query,

```
Select t1.Number, t1.TransactionType, t1.Description, t1.Vendor,
(Select max(t2.BatchId) From table2 t2
 Where t1.Number=t2.Number and t1.TransactionType=t2.TransactionType
 Group By t2.number,t2.transactiontype) As BatchId
From table1 t1
```

I need a second column from table2. Column is called "Result".

Example:

```
table1:
Number, TransactionType, Description, Vendor
1, Type1, Test1, Vendor1
2, Type1, Test2, Vendor2
1, Type2, Test3, Vendor3
3, Type2, Test1, Vendor2

table2:
Number, TransactionType, BatchId, Result
1, Type1, 12, error1
1, Type1, 4, error2
1, Type2, 8, success
3, Type2, 7, success

wanted ResultSet:
Number, TransactionType, Description, Vendor, BatchId, Result
1, Type1, Test1, Vendor1, 12, error2
2, Type1, Test2, Vendor2, null, null
1, Type2, Test3, Vendor3, 8,success
3, Type2, Test1, Vendor2, 7,success
```

The posted query takes care of the first 5 columns. Now how about that last column?

Comment: Add the required table column to your sub-query SELECT statement. IE: (Select max(t2.BatchId), Result From table2 t2 ...

Comment: Subqueries may not return more than one column in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t1.Number, t1.TransactionType, t1.Description, t1.Vendor, t2.BatchId, t2.Result
from table1 t1
left join
(
  select t2.TransactionType, t2.number, t2.Result, t2.BatchId,
    row_number() over (partition by t2.number, t2.TransactionType order by t2.BatchId desc) as BatchNumber
  from table2 t2
) t2 on t1.Number = t2.Number
  and t1.TransactionType = t2.TransactionType
  and t2.BatchNumber = 1
```

If you can be sure that for each row from t1 you have related rows in t2 then it will be better to replace left join with inner join.

**UPD** There was an error which was correctly noticed in the comments. I've changed the query to the right version.

Comment: You have converted the left join to an inner join with your syntax.  add t.batchnumber = 1 to the ON clause not the where clause. http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN

Comment: That did the trick oryol. And no I have no guarantee that a record has been transmitted. So the result table might not have corresponding values. The left join is perfect.